# How do I access content other than document in html extension?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a Firefox extension that gets content from a site and does maths with it. I tested my code in the web console, and it worked fine. However, it does not work when I put it in the format of an extension. I think the problem has something to do with my code referencing game and not document, any clues?

js:

```
bruh1=document.createElement("button");
bruh1.addEventListener("click",function() {
console.log(Game.ObjectsById[0].storedCps);
  var pricearray=[];
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    pricearray[i]=Game.ObjectsById[i].storedCps/Game.ObjectsById[i].price;
  }
  
  var max = pricearray[0];
    
  for (i=0; i<=pricearray.length;i++){
    if (pricearray[i]>max) {
        max=pricearray[i];
    }
  }
    
  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    document.getElementById("productName"+i).innerHTML=Math.round((pricearray[i]/max)*100)/100;
  }
console.log("help");
});
bruh1.innerHTML="efficiency";
document.getElementById("topBar").appendChild(bruh1);
```

manifest:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "le shton de blob cookie clicka",
  "version": "0",

  "description": "gaming hard rn",

  "icons": {
    "89": "icons/89.png"

  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches":["https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/"],
      "js":["cceff.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```